# Python: IndexError immediately after successful evaluation of list at same index

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am processing a tab-delimited data set of almost three million lines. Since I have enough memory, I am loading the entire data file into memory via a list. I then go and clean up inconsistencies with the data row-by-row. After 150,000 lines of successful computation, the program halts with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File     "C:/Users/me/dataset_cleanup_utility/dataset_cleanup.py",     line 466, in <module>
    ROWS_PASSED = passed
  File     "C:/Users/me/dataset_cleanup_utility/dataset_cleanup.py", line 43, in dataset_cleanup
    row = make_consistent(row, row_count)
  File "C:/Users/me/dataset_cleanup_utility/dataset_cleanup.py", line 180, in make_consistent
    row[11] = remove("(STAFF)", "", str(row[11]))
IndexError: string index out of range
```

The code sample that causes this is below:

```
if "(STAFF)" in str(row[11]):
    row[11] = remove("(STAFF)", "", str(row[11]))

def remove(unwanted, wanted, _str):
     s = str(_str).rsplit(unwanted, 1)
    if len(s) == 2:
        return str(s[0]) + wanted + str(s[1])
    else:
        return str(s[0]) + wanted
```

Here, `row` is the list containing all of the columns for a given row and the `IndexError` is being thrown INSIDE the if statement that checks `row[11]`. So what this error is telling me is that the `row[11]` was okay when evaluating the if statement, but inside the if statement, when evaluated again, `row[11]` no longer exists. How could this be if no changes to `row[11]` occurred after the if statement was evaluated?

Comment: If `row` is a list, and you attempted to index an element that doesn't exist, you would get the error `IndexError: list index out of range`.  To get the error `IndexError: string index out of range`, it must be a *string* that you are attempting to index incorrectly.  Check the types of all your variables to make sure they are what you think they are.

Comment: Just to make sure the error is really in that line, can you extract a variable of `str(row[11])`: `tmp_str = str(row[11]); row[11] = remove("(STAFF)", "", tmp_str)`

Comment: If `"(STAFF)"` is the beginning of the string and it is replaced with `""`, could that be the reason? If so, is it possible that Traceback is not giving me all of the details?

Comment: What if `len(s) == 0`?

Comment: If `len(s) == 0`, then the Traceback would show the error occurring in the `remove` function, not in the if statement

Comment: Why don't you catch the exception, and print the value of `row`?

Comment: Yes, I will certainly do that. But it will be hours until the exception is thrown again, given the size of this dataset and how far down the dataset this occurs in. Very difficult to debug.

Comment: The only thing being indexed on that line of code is `row` so it must be a string. I think this mustn't be the actual code. What are the few lines before? Are you sure this is line 180 and not some duplicated code?